# Exit permit or Indian visa for child born in india for US citizens?

Tags: india, us-citizens

My wife and I are US citizens with OCI cards. We had a twin baby last year in October and we are waiting for US passport. How do we apply for an exit permit? Also, can we apply for an Indian visa instead of an exit permit?

Comment: The US does not have Immigration checks when a traveler leaves the US. Thus, there is no "US exit permit." The airline will, however, report your departure to the government, and will require you to show that you can enter whatever countries you're flying to.

Comment: Thanks for the response.My kids are born in india.. my question was on Indian exit visa process. Sorry There was typo it is not IS passport i meant US passport

Comment: @GSS You can edit your question as needed to fix typos.

Comment: "can we apply for an Indian visa instead of an exit permit?": Can't you apply for OCI for the children?

Comment: "We had _a_ twin baby"? Usually, there are two in order to be called twins. My apologies if one didn't make it...

Answer (score 4):

You will need to deal with the [FRRO](https://www.mea.gov.in/visa-related-services-provided-by-FRROs-FROs.htm)

> xii) Other services (this includes registration/grant of visa/exit permission for child born in India, grant of visa to those who have surrendered Indian passport consequent on acquiring foreign passport, registration by those who claim to be refugees etc.)

---

You will want to wait for the passport then the process is [fully online](https://indianfrro.gov.in/eservices/home.jsp), and you will receive the permit by post if granted

> RC/RP, Exit Permit etc would sent by post on the “Address in India” mentioned in the online application form.

You will probably need to apply for an OCI for the children as well, before applying for the permit, to eliminate any issues regarding potential overstays.